# Set margins from Gmail settings

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to set the Gmail margins, but I can't find the option to do that.
Which section of the settings should I to look for?

---

EDIT

1. Default settings (I do not want this)
   [image]
2. Desirable settings
   [image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by Gmail margins and add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hello @Ruben, see the edit please.